# Can I filter the submitted list in p4v to show submits from a few specific users?

Tags: perforce

Using P4V to view our Perforce depot, I'd like to filter the view of the Submitted tab to show check-ins from a select group of users.  So, I tried creating a custom filter which allows specifying a User. However, I'd prefer to list a few users but cannot figure out whether it's possible.

I consulted the Perforce docs and they don't really go into much detail on what's acceptable.  I tried these variations:   `user1,user2`   `user1 user2`   `user1|user2` `user1+user2`

All failed so I thought I'd ask here before throwing in the towel...

Can anyone tell me how to filter the view in P4 to show a select set of users?  Bonus points if I can filter and show all users EXCEPT a particular one. ex: `!tooluser` to hide all automatic submits by a particular tool.

[image: Filter Editor]

*Comment Responses:*
The `[+]/[-]` buttons only add high-level categories and User can only be added once though it is a large edit field (thus my attempts above). Only multiple file path filters can be added with the `[+]` button.

Comment: [This page](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r14.3/manuals/p4v/using.filters.html) of the P4V User's Guide (from four years ago) talks about ```+``` and ```-``` buttons.  Do you have those?  Have you tried them? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm answering my own question with a response I got from Perforce:

```
Hey John - So sorry for your frustration and thank you for reaching out. 
Currently you cannot filter the Submitted tab to show check-ins from a 
select group of users in P4V. But this is a known issue in our backlog. - LH
```